# how to get list of files on ftp in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

In windows phone 8 we can create Ftp client like this

```
FtpWebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create(address) as FtpWebRequest;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
```

but i couldn't find any alternative in windows phone 8.1 universal

Comment: Probably this : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-SocketsFtp-4fc23b33

Answer (score 0):

`FtpWebRequest` was used in Windows Phone Silverlight. Windows Phone 8.1 Universal uses the WinRT api's, not the Silverlight api's.

To download a small file, we can use a `WebRequest` with the RETR method. For large file, it is better to use BackgroundDownloader.

More details in this sample (even though it's Windows 8, the same API is used on WP 8.1 RT): https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWindowsStoreAppFTPDownloa-88a90bd9